# Two Table View. One Getting Data & Other is not showing data

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yDw9.png)

[Selling Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDJTL.png)

I have made two tables ProductTable (tag=1) & Selling Table(tag=2)

ProductTable is showing data correctly
but Selling table is not showing anything only the number of cell.

Pls tell me why this is happening?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    if (tableView.tag==1 )
    {

        return ProductImages.count;
    }

    else
    {

        return MostProductImages.count;
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



if (tableView.tag==1 )
    {
        ProductTableViewCell *cell= [_ProductTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableView"];

    if ([[ProductImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual: [NSNull null] ])
            {
                cell.product_image.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher.png"];
            }

            else

                cell.product_image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Productaddurl stringByAppendingPathComponent:[ProductImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];

    cell.product_name.text= [Product_Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.product_mp.text= [MP objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.product_sp.text= [SP objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.product_image.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    cell.product_name.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    cell.product_mp.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    cell.product_sp.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    cell.heartButton.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        cell.rup.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    [cell.layer setBorderWidth: 0.1];
        [cell.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
        [cell.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [cell.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

        return cell;


    }

       if (tableView.tag==2)
        {

        SellingTableViewCell *cell1= [_SellingTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableCell"];

    if ([[MostProductImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual: [NSNull null] ])

    {
        cell1.selling_image.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher.png"];

    }
    else
 cell1.selling_image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Productaddurl stringByAppendingPathComponent:[MostProductImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]]];

                 cell1.selling_name.text= [MostProduct_Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            //NSLog(@"%@", [MostProduct_Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

            cell1.selling_mp.text= [MostMP objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell1.selling_sp.text= [MostSP objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            cell1.selling_name.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            cell1.selling_mp.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            cell1.selling_sp.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            cell1.heartButton.transform= CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            cell1.selling_image.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

            cell1.selling_name.numberOfLines = 2;

            [cell1.layer setBorderWidth: 0.1];
            [cell1.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
            [cell1.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [cell1.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
                 [cell1.contentView setAlpha:0];
                 [cell1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

            return cell1;
        }

     return nil;
}
```

Comment: did you set delegate and datasource to the Seiling Table?

Comment: Kim, While asking a question on SO, help yourself by helping others understand the question. Add few screenshot along with some code.

Comment: I have connect delegate & data source  to selling table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have some values in `MostProductImages` array.
2. Compare each and every attribute of both the tables. Have you correctly referenced both the tables in your `viewController.swift` file. Have you correctly set the delegate and dataSource for both the tables? Have you set the tags for both the tables correctly?

Hope this helps :)

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", [MostProduct_Name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

I have check these things..data is coming but not visible?

Comment: Did you check the tags for both the tables?